# How to make a loading screen while using three.js and jsonLoader?

Tags: json, three.js

I have a very large amount of texture files and models to load into my project. I am trying to show a status bar or some sort of loading screen while everything is loading. If anyone could give me any info on how to do this that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The minimum required code is just this:

```
THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
};
```

Instead of printing to the console you can for example start the rendering loop "if loaded == total".
Or/And you can update any loading indicater.
(The code is from one of the examples.)

Comment: onProgress actually only returns the path of the current file that is being loaded

Answer (score 8):

You can use a pattern like this to manage the loading process:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

manager.onStart = function( item, loaded, total ) {

    console.log( 'Loading started' );

};

manager.onLoad = function() {

    console.log( 'Loading complete' );

};

manager.onProgress = function( item, loaded, total ) {

    console.log( item, loaded, total );

};

manager.onError = function( url ) {

    console.log( 'Error loading' );

};

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

var texture = loader.load( 'texture.jpg', function ( texture ) {

    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );

} );

var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );

loader.load( 'file.obj', function( object ) {

    // your code

 } );
```

three.js r.85

Comment: these examples are so confusing. Is there like an event or something I can add onto my jsonLoader to find out how far along it is?

Comment: I guess all i need is a way to tell when it is finished loading all of my models and textures. These examples are too fancy I can't tell what is actually useful to me. I already have a finished project and I would have to change a lot just to follow one of these examples.

Comment: I just noticed that the callback function is called when the model is finished loading, so i am guessing that once all of my callback functions are called that means that everything has finished loading. I am going to give this a try.

Comment: .. awesome .....solved my problem .... many thanks .... : ) ,,

"var LoadFontmanager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
LoadFontmanager.onLoad  = function() {
    init();
};

loadFont();
function loadFont() {

    var loader = new THREE.FontLoader(LoadFontmanager);
    loader.load( 'js/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
        main_font = font;
    } );

}"