# three.js How to find out if my scene was loaded

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a quite a few Meshes in my scene, like 30 or so, than I have some light there too. So all these object caused that when I load the page it takes a while to load the page.

My question is, how to find out if my page is loaded. I mean like whole page, not single texture or so. Is it possible? I don't load any .obj or some similar objects. All I have are some geometries with textures, and those lights.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344865/how-to-make-a-loading-screen-while-using-three-js-and-jsonloader) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the amount of children of the scene with:

```
scene.children.length
```

If the amount of children is the same as the amount of all your objects, the scene should be loaded. I'm not sure if it works, but you can give it a try.